# python pexpect & pxssh with sudo and EOF

Tags: python, sudo, eof, pexpect

I make ssh login with this script:

```
import pxssh
import pexpect

s = pxssh.pxssh()
hostname = 'localhost'
username = 'py_worker'
password = 'nicejob'
s.login (hostname, username, password)
print "logged in"
```

Then I want to run some program which in some case may require sudo password and in some case may not require. So I want a scrip which could provide sudo password in those cases when required and just run the program if sudo is not asked.
I thought this code could handle:

```
s.sendline('sudo apt-get check')
i=s.expect(['password', pexpect.EOF])
if i==0:
    print "I give password"
    s.sendline("nicejob")
    s.prompt()
elif i==1:
    print "EOF cought"
    s.prompt()
print s.before
```

Could someone help with code lines which could handle sudo correctly?

Comment: How about giving sudoer permission to the user without password?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about this option. It could be possible, but that is not desired situation. I would search for solution, which could be far more universal and applicable in many different situations.
As an example it could be possible to use such solution for automated ubuntu box installation - one script could install a bunch of required software.
Thanks for suggestion anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

thanks for asking this, it helped me.

youll probably need to flesh out the exceptions and re for the rootprompt but here you go.

```
def sudo(s,password):
    rootprompt = re.compile('.*[$#]')
    s.sendline('sudo -s')
    i = s.expect([rootprompt,'assword.*: '])
    if i==0:
        print "didnt need password!"
        pass
    elif i==1:
        print "sending password"
        s.sendline(password)
        j = s.expect([rootprompt,'Sorry, try again'])
        if j == 0:
            pass
        elif j == 1:
            raise Exception("bad password")
    else:
        raise Exception("unexpected output")
    s.set_unique_promp
```