# subprocess.call not working in PyCharm (linux)

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, subprocess, pycharm

Here's the program:

```
if os.name == 'posix' and getpass.getuser() != 'root':
  from subprocess import call

  call(["sudo", sys.executable, os.path.realpath(__file__), "--root-install"])
```

When I run it from the terminal it works fine:

```
> [sudo] Password for user:
```

But when I run it from PyCharm the terminal just stays blank.
I have also tried setting `stdin=sys.stdin, stdout=sys.stdout` manually, but that did not change anything.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: pycharm terminal doesn't support the sudo getpass method. You probably want `pexpect`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18046508/python-pexpect-pxssh-with-sudo-and-eof

Comment: Thanks for the input. I thought about providing the password to `sudo`, but then how would I aquire said password? `getpass.getpass` does not seem to work in PyCharm either.

Comment: nope, `getpass` also needs the original terminal. You could try to detect it, and if not a normal terminal (testing for `hasattr(sys.stdin,"isatty")`) and if it's not a normal terminal, use some GUI like wx or tk to prompt for a password (hiding the letters)

Comment: `hasattr(sys.stdin,"isatty")` is always `True`. Both in a normal terminal and in PyCharms. Alternatives?

Comment: oh. It's false with Pyscripter. Okay... maybe `hasattr(sys.stdin,"fileno")`

Comment: Both `True` still

Comment: Damn: if PyCharm is so good at faking a _real_ terminal, it should also accept `getpass` :) Then you could use graphical prompt whatever the environment. I heard that `getpass` is outdated/obsolete anyway.

Comment: ... or just work with sudo through call. Why does this have to be so hard. And about the graphical solution: I need sudo to use pip to install all required packages. So any depending package is a deal breaker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyCharm and IDEs generally don't like `getpass`-like inputs. Since `sudo` asks for the password in such a way, it's not runnable from a redirected IDE console.

Redirecting `stdin` from `Popen` won't change anything either.

Workaround: run the `sudo` command from a terminal. Example with `xterm` (sorry, I don't know much about nowadays terminals):

```
call(["xterm","-e","sudo", sys.executable, os.path.realpath(__file__), "--root-install"])
```

Comment: Works! Not pretty but I'm just glad there is _some_ solution. Very clever!

Comment: glad it works! I wonder why I didn't think of that sooner... Running windows here. Other problems :)

Comment: Had some windows issues too, but I know how to work around _those_ haha, linux hacks are new for me. A standalone python program which installs its on dependencies surely is a challange for me.